# Place present on Google Maps, but not showing in Places API call

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using Google Places API in my Android app to detect bike shops in the user's proximity. I have a problem with this shop (Joy Ride Bicycles): https://www.google.ro/maps/place/Joy+Ride/@47.03567,-122.818342,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x54910b4572c99c39:0x340b219b8ac15ba1

Although it's present on Google Maps, it isn't returned when I make a call to the Google Nearby Places API. I have tried with different ranges locations. I've had similar issues with other shops.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be multiple reason according to [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/faq#why_are_some_places_not_returned_when_i_filter_by_type)

> **Why are some Places not returned when I filter by type?**
>
> It's possible that the place you are looking for has not yet been
>   categorized. All places are categorized as the generic type
>   "establishment" until Google has enough data about a place to
>   categorize it as one of the supported place types.
>
> As a workaround you can pass the place type to the keyword parameter.
>   The keyword parameter is matched to: name, type, address, and customer
>   reviews.
>
> If you would like to add the category type to a place listing
>   yourself, submit a place edit. Once the edit has been approved and
>   published it will appear using the correct type filtering.
>
> **Why are some nearby places not returned?**
>
> By default, the Places API sorts results by prominence within the
>   supplied radius. A Nearby Search request can return up to 60 results,
>   split across three pages. If a Place ranks 22nd in prominence, it will
>   appear on the second page of results which you can access through
>   paging. If a Place ranks greater than 60th in prominence it will not
>   be included in the search result, even if it is closer to the center
>   of your search.
>
> You can sort your results by distance instead of prominence by setting
>   the rankby parameter in your query to distance and omitting the radius
>   parameter. Relevance will be ignored and places will be returned in
>   order of distance from location.
>
> If you are filtering your request by type, some results may be
>   filtered out of the response.